# Using client.run() and client.close() in a loop gives "session is closed" on the second run

Tags: python, selenium, discord, discord.py, bots

Warning: complete discord.py noob here (and Python in general).
I'm trying to make a Discord bot that would warn me when an product is available, so I have a main
.py file that runs a loop with selenium firefox that checks the availability, and that part runs well.
Inside that loop, when the product is available,  I am trying to use a function that connects the Discord Bot and warns me. I can then interact with the bot via discord and tell it to keep looking for more, which disconnects the bot, and the program comes out of the main loop, until it gets back to the function that calls the discord bot (so it reconnects the bot, waits for an interaction, and repeat).
So, it works well the first time, but on the second run of the loop the Bot won't reconnect, and tells me that Session is closed (the program keeps going though). Here is the code of the Discord Bot function:

```
import discord
import time

#Discord Bot parameters
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
channelFirefox = [here goes the discord channel ID]

#Tarjetas
t1 = ["1111","1/11","111"]
t2 = ["2222","2/22","222"]
t3 = ["3333","3/33","333"]
t4 = ["444","4/44","444"]


def botFunction(channelFirefox):

    #Discord Bot routines
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        channel = client.get_channel(channelFirefox)
        print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
        await channel.send('Productos pillados !')
        await channel.send('Para comprar: comprar t1/t2/t3/t4')
        await channel.send('Para continuar: y ')
        await channel.send('Para parar: parar ')
                
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):

        global procesoCompra,tarjeta
        
        if message.channel.id == channelFirefox:

            if message.author == client.user:
                return

            if message.content.startswith('comprar t1'):
                await message.channel.send('Comprando con tarjeta 1')
                procesoCompra = "comprar"
                tarjeta = t1
                await client.close()
                
                
            if message.content.startswith('comprar t2'):
                await message.channel.send('Comprando con tarjeta 2')
                procesoCompra = "comprar"
                tarjeta = t2
                await client.close()
                

            if message.content.startswith('comprar t3'):
                await message.channel.send('Comprando con tarjeta 3')
                procesoCompra = "comprar"
                tarjeta = t3
                await client.close() 
                    

            if message.content.startswith('comprar t4'):
                await message.channel.send('Comprando con tarjeta 4')
                procesoCompra = "comprar"
                tarjeta = t4
                await client.close()
                
                
            if message.content.startswith('y'):
                await message.channel.send('Continua buscando')
                procesoCompra = "y"
                tarjeta = ["000","0/0","0"]   
                await client.close()
                
                
            if message.content.startswith('parar'):
                await message.channel.send('Este perfil ha sido parado')
                procesoCompra = "stop"
                tarjeta = ["000","0/0","0"]
                await client.close()
                    
    
    client.run([HERE GOES THE BOT TOKEN])
    
    return procesoCompra,tarjeta
```

Basically, I want to be able to run this function multiple times, but it seems like client.run() and client.close() cannot be "looped".
Any help would be appreciated !

At first I had the function inside the main code but I was receiving the same error, so I tried to put it outside of the file but I am still getting the same error (the program keeps going despite the error).
The main program works well, I was using it before but interacting via the command console, I just decided to add control via Discord Bot instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what the purpose of your bot is? Im confused as to why you have this: `await client.close` What is the purpose in closing your bot's connection to discord after going through what I presume is a command? If you can let me know about that I think I'll be much more able to help. Also, may I suggest using the `@client.command` decorator instead of creating and calling commands through the `on_message` event? It's in my opinion much easier and works a lot better. Here is the link to that in the Discord.py API reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#commands

Comment: It checks the availability of an item (tickets) on a website, and clicks it if it is available, reserving it for some time, then it is supposed to activate the discord bot for awaiting instructions. 
I use await client.close because after the command, I want to be able to go back to the main loop (sending "y" to the discord bot), buy the item (sending "comprar t1") or stopping the program (sending "parar"). I can't do so if the function of the Discord bot is active.
I searched if it was possible to pause the bot and come back to it, but i did not find any function. 
I'll look, thanks